# Why is an inline-level box in the same line box as its parent inline-level box?

Tags: html, css, w3c

The documentation states that the boxes (siblings) are distributed **one next to the other** in the Inline Layout,

> An inline formatting context is established by a block container box
> that contains no block-level boxes. In an inline formatting context,
> **boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the
> top of a containing block.** Horizontal margins, borders, and padding
> are respected between these boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically
> in different ways: their bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the
> baselines of text within them may be aligned. **The rectangular area
> that contains the boxes that form a line is called a line box.**

but, where does it say that an `inline-level` box (`#child`) will be placed on the same *line box* as its parent `inline-level` box (`#parent`)?

```html
<div>
  <span id="parent">
    Hi
    <span id="child">Hello</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I understand that `inline-level` sibling boxes are next to each other, but the parent-child relationship in Inline Layout I don't understand.

Comment: The _text node_ containing "Hi", and your span containing "Hello", are displayed on the same line. There is no parent-child relationship between that text node and the span.

Comment: hi @CBroe, so, by default, any inline elements (no matter how nested they are) will be on the same line box?

Answer (score -1):

span by default is displayed as inline block, thus when you add additional span inside it, it will automatically show up in the same line.

here are some visual examples for you to understand it a little bit better:

```css
#secondChild{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="parent">
    Hi
    <span id="child">Hello</span>
  </span>
</div>


<div>
  <p id="pParent">
    Hi
    <span id="pChild">Hello</span>
  </p>
</div>


<div>
  <span id="secondParent">
    Hi
    <span id="secondChild">Hello</span>
  </span>
</div>
```